# Python - iterate every combination of two lists as a search

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-itertools

Example:

```
 import itertools
 color = ['Red','White','Blue']
 shape = ['Circle','Square']
 combo = list(itertools.product(color,shape))
 print(combo)
```

results: [[('Red', 'Circle'), ('Red', 'Square'), ('White', 'Circle'), ('White', 'Square'), ('Blue', 'Circle'), ('Blue', 'Square')]]

Getting every combination works fine. What I want to do now is search each combination seperately. This is where I'm getting stuck.

Example:

```
 for searches in combo:
     driver.get("https://www.bing.com")
     search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sb_form_q")))
     search.send_keys(str(combo))
     search.submit()
```

The result is searching all combinations at once instead of each combination separately in a loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're combo variable is exactly what you've put here you have a doubly nested list, so when you iterate over `combo` you're iterating of a list of lists with a single element, which is a list of your combination tuples. When defining combo you don't need those outer square brackets.

Comment: I removed the brackets but got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also send_keys `searches` not `combo`. Searches will be a tuple and I assume you intend to send keys as "Red Circle" etc.

Try this

```
import itertools
color = ['Red','White','Blue']
shape = ['Circle','Square']
combo = list(itertools.product(color,shape))
print(combo)

for searches in combo:
  print(" ".join(searches))
```